# How do i get actual value instead of placeholder while loading bean?

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the placeholder instead of its property value while loading the beans.

properties file

```
tm.web.keystore.key.password=WaheeD
tm.web.tcp.backlog=1024
tm.web.min.jetty.threads=8
tm.web.max.jetty.threads=25
```

appcontext.xml file

```
<bean class="com.intel.ssg.mconsole.core.web.WebServer" id="webServer">
    <property name="port" value="${tm.web.port}" />
    <property name="address" value="${tm.web.address}" />
    <property name="warLocation" value="${tm.home}/mconsole.war" />
    <property name="secure" value="${tm.web.secure}" />
    <property name="keystoreLocation" value="${tm.web.keystore.location}" />
    <property name="keystorePassword" value="WaheeD" />
    <property name="keyPassword" value="${tm.web.keystore.key.password}" />
    <property name="tcpBacklog" value="${tm.web.tcp.backlog}" />
    <property name="minJettyThreads" value="${tm.web.min.jetty.threads}" />
    <property name="maxJettyThreads" value="${tm.web.max.jetty.threads}" />
</bean>
```

Loading it via marshaller

```
 try {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getAppContextFile());
     try {
         return (Beans) JAXBUtil.getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(fis);
     } finally {
         fis.close();
     }
```

In Beans,I am getting value as ${tm.weberver.port}for bean webServer port rathen than its exact value..suppose 8443 port.

Comment: why do u expect that properties injection will happen automatically without instantiation of ApplicationContext? in your example you just reading XML file, nothing more - correct?

Comment: right..So how can i load appcontext into beans using marshaller?

Comment: Dont do it, use the an appcontext loader, see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

You post a properties file that doesn't have any property for port number, a context file that uses `${tm.web.port}`, and your text says that you're using `${tm.weberver.port}`.

I see three possible places for your mistake. That's assuming that you are actually setting other properties. If not, see Andrey's comment.

Comment: there is tm.web.port in properties file, just i have not write all code here. ${tm.weberver.port}. was a typing mistake..

Answer (score 1):

You dont need need to expressly load beans from your ApplicationContext.xml.

Make sure the following are present:

- In your ApplicationContext.xml there must be a property loader for your property file, e.g. [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)
- In your application, a application context loader is required. There may one built into your current framework e.g. WebApplicationContext in [DispatcherServlet for Spring MVC](http://www.javabeat.net/2011/01/spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet-example/). If you're starting out you can use [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have already done all these and my application is up and running properly.There is no issue in that.

Comment: I want to read the properties file using Rest. I have opened a following REST call for this: '@RequestMapping(value = "/beans/{id}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getBeanPropertyValue(@PathVariable("id") String beanId,
            @PathVariable("name") String propertyName)'....Suppose a resquest come to know about port i,e https://localhost:8443/admin/webServer/port, The value should come as 8443 but right now i am getting placeholder for it.